# Problems importing local JSON with Request.JSON in MooTools

Tags: javascript, json, mootools

I'm trying to use Request.JSON in mooTools to bring in an object from a file I called "sample1.json" that is stored in the same folder locally. I did this successfully using jQuery's "$.getJSON()", which was trivially easy, but encountered difficulty doing this in mooTools.

Here's my script:

```
var jsonRequest=new Request.JSON({
    url: 'sample1.json', 
    onComplete: function(){
        alert('JSON imported successfully!');
    }
});
```

And here's how 'sample1.json' looks:

```
{
"string": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog",
"number":1,
"object":{"width":1000,"height":2000},
"array":[0,60],
"null":""
}
```

I never get the alert message that I'm hoping for; I feel like it's a trivial question, but after doing several hours of research trying to understand my error, I'm not getting anywhere. I appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply you're never sending the request. `new Request.JSON()` simple creates a new request object. You need to call `send` to actually start the request. Also, `onComplete` is called when the request is done successful or not, but `onSuccess` is what will have your json response:

```
var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
    url: 'sample1.json', 
    onComplete: function(){
        alert('Request Complete!');
    },
    onSuccess: function(jsonResponse){
      // jsonResponse is the actual json in 'sample1.json'
    }
}).send(); // or jsonRequest.send() later if needed
```

Comment: Just tried out your solution. It appears it is sending the request now; only problem is that I'm getting an "Access is denied" error message now. Not sure what is different between mooTools handling of this request and jQuery, but I do not get a similar message when I use my jQuery solution. I am going to assume that my issue is related to the fact that I'm not in a true dev environment and don't have the right tools to do this properly. All the same, I really appreciate the help, thanks!